# Как подписать точки в matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook

Построил график по трем точкам в jupiter notebook

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

%matplotlib inline

table = [
    [0,-2,2],
    [3,0,6],
    ['A(0;3)','B(-2;0)','C(2;6)']
]

df = pd.DataFrame(table, index=['x','y','Точка'], columns=['A','B','C'])

X = [x for x in df.loc['x']]
Y = [y for y in df.loc['y']]

plt.plot(X, Y, marker='o');
plt.annotate('A(0;3)', xy=(df['A']['x'] + 0.2,df['A']['y']))
plt.annotate('B(-2;0)', xy=(df['B']['x'] + 0.2,df['B']['y']))
plt.annotate('C(2;6)', xy=(df['C']['x'] + 0.2,df['C']['y']));
```

Как подписать точки на графике, то есть возле каждой точки поставить A(0;3), B(-2;0), C(2;6)' соответствующую подпись ?
Я это сделал по кривому через аннотацию, уверен так не нужно делать, как правильно подписать точки ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Я бы делал это так:

сначала транспонируем DF для удобства:

```
In [217]: dft = df.T

In [218]: dft
Out[218]:
    x  y    Точка
A   0  3   A(0;3)
B  -2  0  B(-2;0)
C   2  6   C(2;6)
```

Рисуем точки соединенные отрезками:

```
In [219]: plt.plot(dft['x'], dft['y'], marker='o')
Out[219]: [<matplotlib.lines.Line2D at 0xcd4d588>]

In [220]: ax = plt.gca()
```

добавляем подписи:

```
In [221]: dft.apply(lambda x: ax.annotate(x['Точка'], (x['x'] + 0.2, x['y'])), axis=1)
Out[221]:
A      Annotation(0.2,3,'A(0;3)')
B    Annotation(-1.8,0,'B(-2;0)')
C      Annotation(2.2,6,'C(2;6)')
dtype: object
```

Результат:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

сначала получаем объект `ax`

```
ax = plt.gca()
```

Из docstring:

```
In [227]: plt.gca?
Signature: plt.gca(**kwargs)
Docstring:
Get the current :class:`~matplotlib.axes.Axes` instance on the
current figure matching the given keyword args, or create one.
```

потом добавляем подписи:

`dft.apply(func, axis=1)` - выполняет/вызывает функцию `func` для каждой строки (`axis=1`) DataFrame. Т.е. `ax.annotate()` вызовется с соответствующими параметрами для каждой строки

Comment: Объясните вот эти методы ax = plt.gca() и dft.apply